# How to resume sidekiq jobs (long running jobs) after restart in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis, background-process, sidekiq

I am using [Mina-Sidekiq](https://github.com/Mic92/mina-sidekiq) to shutdown and restart sidekiq while deployment.

I have 5-6 jobs running whey are heavy duty jobs will continue to run for long time, But whenever I do `mina deploy` It restarts sidekiq and removes all running jobs.

Here is deploy script

```
task :deploy do
  deploy do
     # stop accepting new workers
     invoke :'sidekiq:quiet'
     invoke :'git:clone'
     invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
     ...

     to :launch do
       ...
       invoke :'sidekiq:restart'
     end
  end
end
```

How to resume all current running jobs with restart/deployment?

Comment: If it restarts Sidekiq "correctly", the jobs should restart without incident.  Needs to use USR1 + TERM.  If it's using KILL, that's a serious bug.

Comment: What is USR1 + TERM ?

Comment: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#overview